# Plot major ticks on y-axis of loglog plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, loglog

[image]
I am trying to plot the major ticks on the y-axis of the loglog plot in matplotlib. The plot has ticks ($10^{0}, 10^{-5}, 10^{-10},...$) on the y-axis but I want to indicate the tick marks in between the intervals like for $10^{-1}, 10^{-2}, 10^{-3}, 10^{-4}$ without actual display of ticks.

```py
locmin = matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator(base=10.0,subs=(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8),numticks=5)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(locmin)
```

I expect the output to include the major tick marks for each of the values ($10^{-1}, 10^{-2},...$) in the y-axis but with ticks display of only the values with a span of $10^{-5}$.

Comment: You should maybe include an image of what what you have currently looks like.

Comment: I have added the image. I would like to have the tick marks for the intermediate points between 2 major points on the y-axis.

Comment: You would need to use a minor locator for those ticks that you don't want to label.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Can you please be bit more explicit? I did try using minor locator but didn't work.

Comment: If the question contains an explicit [mcve] of what goes wrong, I can tell explicitely what you need to change, yes.